# Cannot disable systemd serial-getty service

Tags: raspberry-pi, archlinux, tty, gpio, systemd

On Raspberry Pi with Arch Linux there is a service active called `serial-getty@AMA0`.

The unit file is: /usr/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service

As root I can invoke

```
systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0
systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0
```

But after reboot the service is enabled and running again.

Why is the service enabled after disabling it? How can I disable it permanent?

UPDATE

systemd uses [generators](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Generators/) at /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/ is a binary called systemd-getty-generator. This binary runs at system start and adds the symlink serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service to `/run/systemd/generator/getty.target.wants`.

I eventually found a dirty solution. I commented out all actions in /usr/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service. The service did appear to start anyway, but without blocking ttyAMA0.

Comment: Take a look at where the symlinks to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` are placed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The correct way to stop a service ever being enabled again is to use:

```
systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

(using *ttyAMA0* as the example in this case). This will add a link to null to the entry for that service.

Comment: Could suffix "`.service`" [be omitted](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)?

Answer (score -5):

Try this code:

```
system("systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service");
system("systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service");
```

I use it, and it works well.

Comment: What is the context? From a Bash script? A Python script? A Perl script? A C program? Something else?

Comment: yes , you can use system(); in c++ in linux .for example you can use system(" data") ,system(" dir") ,system(" ls") in  c++ .it run bash script (system script in linux)

Comment: I've logged in for the first time in a long time to leave this comment. Please don't use C's `system` function. It has well known security issues. It's especially bad in this case, because manipulating systemd often requires root privileges.

edit: I'll add this for context https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177